# What drives the multi-screen rating in AdSense scoreboard?

Tags: seo, google-adsense

On my AdSense scoreboard, I am getting a one star rating for my multi-screen. however, I am getting five stars for the other categories. My site is validated and compatible for all platforms. What drives the multi-screen rating?

Comment: I am not an expert on this, but for my site, I found that the issue is as a page is scaled, how does it perform in regard to readability? The primary metric I think Google looks at is how fonts scale in pixels. This is something I have to work on for myself, but there are CSS differences that need to be made for smaller screens. While I do not have an answer right now, I can tell you to check how your fonts scale and research how to make them scale properly for smaller screens. The answers are on the net and I think Google has some valuable words on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your multi-screen rating is based on the number of pages that are optimized for multiple screen sizes. i.e. If a number of your pages are not optimized for mobile/tablet viewers, your performance rating will suffer as a result.

To increase this score:

- Use a responsive layout. Pages that force the user to zoom in will negatively impact your score, simply because Google feels as though zooming has a negative impact on the user's experience. Also, make sure that you're using the viewport META tag correctly.
- According to Google: The less scrolling, the better.
- Make use of Adsense's new responsive ad units. If you're displaying regular Adsense units to mobile users, there's a good chance that the layout will be negatively affected. In some cases, horizontal ad units will widen the layout of your site, leading to horizontal scrolling (I've witnessed this on several "responsive" websites).

Something else that is worth taking into account:

> Your score in the multi-screen category will measure what percentage
>   of your pages are multi-screen optimized and compare this percentage
>   to that of other AdSense publishers.

[Source](http://adsense.blogspot.ie/2013/12/boost-your-multi-screen-strategy-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

The multiscreen score is driven by the visual performance of your pages with ads and how they are displayed to mobile and desktop users. 
The multiscreen score factors all page-views across your account, but looking at a page-by-page analysis, you can improve your overall score.

The best tool for evaluating how to improve this is Google's own Page speed tool.

http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/

Check out the User Experience Tab under both desktop and mobile and get optimizing!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

as you can see my adsense are full score!

here's my  suggestion if you want to get full score!

you need to get score 92 above speed score! or in other words, you need to buy premium themes, but I think you'll need to optimize your themes, from java, css font and etc! if you can do by yourself then its good for you! there free tools everywehere, I am sure you can find it with G Help!

but, here the bad news! even if you already reach max adsense score, it doesnt mean, your income will change dramatically, unless you have ten or hundreds thousand visitor, not page view though! cause for some cases, you can get ten thousand page view with only thousand visitor i.e 1 visitor visit 10 pages!